# Ember "needs" ObjectController seems inaccessible

Tags: ember.js

I have the following router in Ember:

```
  this.resource('clients', function() {
      this.route('new');
      this.route('client', { path: '/:id' }, function() {
        this.route('profile');
        this.route('sessions');
        this.route('payments');
      });   
  });
```

From within the `clients.client.payments` route I'd like to be able to access the client information from the parent controller `clients.client` but I'm struggling to find a way to do this. Currently from within the clients.client.payments controller I have:

```
needs: ['clients'],
client: computed.alias('controllers.clients'),
```

This works fine to connect to the array of client records but if I instead use:

```
needs: ['client'],
client: computed.alias('controllers.client'),
```

I get an error saying that it can not find the controller. I am now considering changing 'client' from a *route* to a *resource* (with the hope that this will resolve my problem) but is there really no way to achieve the results I'm looking for as-is?

---

based on on suggestion to try "clientsClient" in needs I have added the following to the clients.client.payments controller:

```
needs: ['clientsClient']
```

I also tried the more explicit:

```
needs: ['controller:clientsClient']
```

but in both cases I get the following error:

[image: error]

Very oddly recursive. I add "a" and it errors out saying it needs "a".

> Note: the clients.client controller *is* defined explicitly as suggested

---

It was also suggested that dot notation (aka, `needs: ['clients.client']`) would be the way to go ... I actually tried that earlier as that was my first thought too but that results in a clearer error message:

> needs must not specify dependencies with periods in their names (controller:clients.client)

Comment: It'd be `clientsClient` since routes inherit the namespace from their parent, remember you also should have defined a `clientsClient` controller.

Comment: I tried this but got a strangely recursive error message as a result. I've updated the question to show the results of this attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use forward slashes

```
needs: ['clients', 'clients/client'],
client: computed.alias('controllers.clients/client'),
```

Comment: Ok getting closer I think. The "needs" is not throwing any errors but the computed alias is. At least when I try to use the inspector I get the error that needs does not include `clients`.

Comment: yup, just changing the alias needs to `needs: ['clients','clients/client']` seems to work.

Comment: uh oh. Just found a further problem. While there are no errors the alias does not actually resolve (it's "undefined").

Comment: to my shock and horror the answer appears to be that the alias needs the forward slash too. Ugly. If you can update this answer I'll remark it as correct: `client: computed.alias('controllers.clients/client')`

Comment: @ken I updated it as soon as you commented. some of this stuff isn't in the docs

Comment: thanks. yeah the docs really should cover this kind of use case thoroughly too. what's the best way to alert the team on this ... do you know?